# Changes made to my React app does not reflect in production build due to service-worker workbox-precaching

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, workbox

I have a service-worker.js file for my React app.

Whenever I make changes to the JavaScript, image assets, or styles (CSS) files, the changes are reflected correctly in the local build. However, when I push the changes to production, the old webpage is still loading in the browser. Also, clearing the cache in the browser will clear the production cache, and the new changes then appear.

How can I avoid this issue? I want to see the new changes in browser when I build the production version. Do I need to add any version control to the service-worker.js workbox-precaching?

Thank you for your help.

```
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */

// This service worker can be customized!
// See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules
// for the list of available Workbox modules, or add any other
// code you'd like.
// You can also remove this file if you'd prefer not to use a
// service worker, and the Workbox build step will be skipped.

import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core'
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration'
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching'
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing'
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies'

clientsClaim()

// Precache all of the assets generated by your build process.
// Their URLs are injected into the manifest variable below.
// This variable must be present somewhere in your service worker file,
// even if you decide not to use precaching. See https://cra.link/PWA
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST)

// Set up App Shell-style routing, so that all navigation requests
// are fulfilled with your index.html shell. Learn more at
// https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell
const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$')
registerRoute(
  // Return false to exempt requests from being fulfilled by index.html.
  ({ request, url }) => {
    // If this isn't a navigation, skip.
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
      return false
    } // If this is a URL that starts with /_, skip.

    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
      return false
    } // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains // a file extension, skip.

    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false
    } // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.

    return true
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html')
)

// An example runtime caching route for requests that aren't handled by the
// precache, in this case same-origin .png requests like those from in public/
registerRoute(
  // Add in any other file extensions or routing criteria as needed.
  ({ url }) =>
    url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith('.png'), // Customize this strategy as needed, e.g., by changing to CacheFirst.
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      // Ensure that once this runtime cache reaches a maximum size the
      // least-recently used images are removed.
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
)

// This allows the web app to trigger skipWaiting via
// registration.waiting.postMessage({type: 'SKIP_WAITING'})
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting()
  }
})

// Any other custom service worker logic can go here.
```